# Using BASH, how can I retrieve text between parenthesis?

Tags: bash

I've searched for this very question on this site, but either they use REGEX ( I have no clue how to use that in BASH, or it's not quite similar enough of a problem so I can use the examples.

Basically, I have an html file that has the info I need in a set of parenthesis.

for example:

Merry Christmas (english)
Feliz Navidad (spanish)

I'm trying to take the data from the html and put it into either a string or echo it out to a filename for comparison.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your example does not look like an HTML file. Can you clarify exactly what your expected input and expected output would be?

Comment: I've just removed the non-essential parts. I can put the <H1></H1> in there, but if the program is searching, the example html code isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is very vague so it's hard to tell what are exactly your requirements, but the following command will find and print all the parentheses from the file:

```
grep -oP '\([^)]+\)' input.html
```

Comment: That works. I just need to clean up my program to make it fit. I did +1 you, but I'm too new for it to record.

Comment: could do `grep -o '([^)]\+)'` as well :) `-P` would help if output is needed without the `()`